# Kivy: Generate dynamically buttons on the second, third... etc screens

Tags: python, dynamic, kivy, screen

I am new in Kivy: python. I am trying to do an application using ScreenManager. The idea, that I have a map of maps and keys of maps should generate buttons on several screens. For instance:
map: {user1: {thing1: value1, thing2, value2}, user2: {thing1: value1...}}
The first screen will have two buttons in scrollview: user1 and user2.
Collection of buttons on the next screen will be thing1, thingN depending on what "user_name" user has pressed. This is just "toy" project, here I am studying the Kivy

I have some global variables. In the first screen the global variable "user_name" is initialized depending on what user has pressed on the first screen. Then in the class of the second screen I tried using map_of_maps[user_name].keys() and place these keys as buttons on the second screen.

```
# kivy_test.py

class MyMainApp(App):
    gapi = gAPI("tilit.txt")
    gapi.file_download()
    gapi.parse_downloaded_file()
    global data
    global user_name
    global account
    data = gapi.get_data()
    user_name = None
    account = None
    def build(self):
        return kv

class MainWindow(Screen):
    f_view = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.create_scrollview)

    def create_scrollview(self, inst):
        base = data.keys()
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1)
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter("height"))

        for element in base:
            button = Button(text=str(element), size_hint=(1, 0.1))
            button.bind(on_press=self.on_scrbutton_pressed)
            layout.add_widget(button)
        scrollview = ScrollView(size=(Window.width, Window.height))
        scrollview.add_widget(layout)
        self.f_view.add_widget(scrollview)

    def on_scrbutton_pressed(self, instance):
        user_name = instance.text
        print(instance.text)

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    s_view = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(SecondWindow,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.create_scrollview)

    def create_scrollview(self, inst):
        base = data[user_name].keys() # Here I have a problem
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1)
        layout.bind(minimum_height = layout.setter("height"))

        for element in base:
            button = Button(text = str(element), size_hint=(1,0.1))
            button.bind(on_press=self.on_scrbutton_pressed)
            layout.add_widget(button)
        scrollview = ScrollView(size=(Window.width, Window.height))
        scrollview.add_widget(layout)
        self.s_view.add_widget(scrollview)

    def on_scrbutton_pressed(self, instance):
        print(instance.text)
```

While running the code I have an error: base = data[user_name].keys(). KeyError: None

```
# my.kv

# Filename: my.kv
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:
    ThirdWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"
    f_view: f_view

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1

        ScrollView:
            id : f_view

#        Button:
#            text: "User1"
#            on_release:
#                app.root.current = "second"
#                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

#        Button:
#            text: "User2"
#            on_release:
#                app.root.current = "second"
#                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"


<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"
    s_view : s_view

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1

        ScrollView:
            id : s_view

        Button:
            text: "Add"


<ThirdWindow>:
    name: "third"
    t_view : t_view

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        id : t_view
```

And one more question: How to perform transitions between screens in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem 1 - KeyError

```
     base = data[user_name].keys()  # Here I have a problem
 KeyError: None
```

### Root Cause

When Kivy process your kv file, it instantiates `WindowManager` object as the root, and it also instantiates its children, `MainWindow` and `SecondWindow`. While instantiating `SecondWindow`, it invoked the constructor (`__init__`) and method `create_scrollview`. It threw a KeyError because the global variable, `user_name` contains the initial value of `None` which does not exist in the dictionary type, `data`.

### Solution

Add `global user_name` in method `on_scrbutton_pressed` of `class MainWindow` before populating `user_name`. Without `global user_name`, Python creates a new local variable when `instance.text` is assigned to `user_name`.

## Problem 2

> How to perform transitions between screens in this case?

### Solution

1. Each screen has by default a property manager that gives you the
   instance of the ScreenManager used. Add the following into method
   `on_scrbutton_pressed` of `class MainWindow`.

   ```
       self.manager.current = "second"
       self.manager.transition.direction = "left"
   ```
2. In `class Secondwindow`, remove constructor and replace method `create_scrollview(self, inst)` with `on_pre_enter(self)`
3. In `class MainWindow`, replace constructor, `__init__` with `on_pre_enter(self):`
4. Add method `on_pre_leave` to remove widgets added to prevent duplicates

## Snippets

```
class MainWindow(Screen):
    f_view = ObjectProperty(None)

    def on_pre_enter(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.create_scrollview)
    ...

    def on_pre_leave(self):
        self.f_view.clear_widgets()

    def on_scrbutton_pressed(self, instance):
        global user_name
        user_name = instance.text
        print(instance.text)
        self.manager.current = "second"
        self.manager.transition.direction = "left"


class SecondWindow(Screen):
    s_view = ObjectProperty(None)

    def on_pre_enter(self):
        base = data[user_name].keys()
        ...

    def on_pre_leave(self):
        self.s_view.clear_widgets()
```

Comment: Thank you for so comprehensive answer! You really helped me.

Answer (score -1):

I've implemented almost the same thing in my app too.

- I have a list of chapter names as keys and their summaries as the
  values.
- When the user enters the screen, the keys() are called and
  buttons are created.
- Depending on the button clicked, the summary is
  displayed on the next screen

Here's how I coded it (Snippets)

```
class chapter_list(Screen):
    def on_pre_enter(self):
        self.buttons = []
        for i in flamingo.keys(): #for loop to generate buttons
            button = Button(text=str(i),height=150) #the text on the button is the chapter name
            button.bind(on_press=self.pressed) #when the button is clicked, the function pressed on called
            self.ids.fgrid.add_widget(button) #added to the flamingogrid
            self.buttons.append(button)
```

Here the `fgrid` is the `id:` of the `Layout`(GridLayout in this case) I choose for this `screen` in the `kv` file

The `self.buttons = []` is just to collect the buttons so that I can remove them on the screen exit.

Let me know if this was helpful.